# ZCompress causes access violation Delphi Xe8

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

using the ZLib library's  `ZCompress();` function when having `System.Sensors, System.Sensors.Components` also in the uses clause causes an Access Violation on this line

```
function deflateInit(var strm: z_stream; level: Integer): Integer;
begin
  Result := deflateInit_(strm, level,
    ZLIB_VERSION, SizeOf(z_stream));
end;
```

How can I fix, or is there a work around? iOS FMX Delphi Xe8

Comment: Have you searched on Quality Portal? Might already be reported.

Comment: I just searched now - couldn't find it reported. Will post as an issue there once Delphi support emails me back to confirm it is a bug